# Concatenate list of lists in R

Tags: r

I have a list TF2Gene[1326] which looks like

```
view(TF2Gene)

structure(list(Sp1=c("a","b","c"),p53=c("x","y","z"),Elk1=c("1","2","3"),...))
```

So its basically a list of 1326 lists.

Now I want to concatenate the values of these lists in 1 so that I can find the unique members. What I am doing is:

```
cols <- unique(unlist(TF2Gene))
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I think you're mixing up terminologies here... you have a list whose elements are vectors. You want to concatenate them within each element of the list? as in: abc, xyz, 123 etc..?

Comment: So in the values above, you would want to end up with 9 unique values? A vector of `c("a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3")`?

Comment: @user1844024, for the list you've shown, what's the output you expect?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Exactly!

Comment: @Arun: Like David mentioned it should be a concatenation of the values

Comment: Then, what you're doing is right.

Comment: @Arun Thanks! I was a bit confused, dint know how to check the results. I just made a smaller list and tried on it. Works.

Comment: Useful! I also found that you can also concentate lists of lists into a single list using `unlist` too, by passing `recursive=FALSE`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to do it. On the example above the result would be a vector like:

```
c("a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3")
```

Answer (score 3):

That's only going to work if your lists have atomic elements. Mine usually don't. Try this instead.

```
do.call(c, list (list( 3,4,5 ) , list( "a","b" )))
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 5

[[4]]
[1] "a"

[[5]]
[1] "b"
```